# How to construct google analytics query to avoid quota limits?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

This is one part of my request. And I have 725 those kind of requests for each day in 2 year span.

I am getting analytics for 30 days traffic for certain dataset I am creating.

When I try to query the analytics for all 725 datasets I get quota error `Requests per user per 100 seconds` even though I put `time.pause(2)` before each request.

Is there something else I can do to avoid hitting the API quota?

```
{
   "reportRequests":[
      {
         "viewId":"104649158",
         "dateRanges":[
            {
               "startDate":"2017-12-01",
               "endDate":"2017-12-31"
            }
         ],
         "metrics":[
            {
               "expression":"ga:pageviews"
            },
            {
               "expression":"ga:uniquePageviews"
            },
            {
               "expression":"ga:pageviewsPerSession"
            },
            {
               "expression":"ga:timeOnPage"
            },
            {
               "expression":"ga:avgTimeOnPage"
            },
            {
               "expression":"ga:entrances"
            },
            {
               "expression":"ga:entranceRate"
            },
            {
               "expression":"ga:exitRate"
            },
            {
               "expression":"ga:exits"
            }
         ],
         "dimensions":[
            {
               "name":"ga:pagePathLevel2"
            }
         ],
         "dimensionFilterClauses":[
            {
               "filters":[
                  {
                     "dimensionName":"ga:pagePathLevel2",
                     "operator":"REGEXP",
                     "expressions":[
                        "23708|23707|23706|23705|23704|23703|23702|23701|23700|23699|23698|23697|23696|23695|23694|23693|23692"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) You should increase the user quota to 1000 requests (if not done already)** by going into your Coogle Cloud Console -> Top-left Menu -> APIs & Services -> Analytics Reporting API -> Quota:

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/quotas

[image]

[image]

**2) You could increase the time range** and use the [`ga:yearMonth`](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/#ga:yearMonth) dimension to still get your monthly breakdown. **However you might face sampling issues**: since your query is "custom" (you use a filter + dimension), [sampling will apply if for the given time range the total number of sessions at property level exceeds 500K](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en) (regardless of how many are actually included in the response). In this case there is no absolute answer, you have to find the time ranges that suit you best. [samplesReadCounts / samplingSpaceSizes](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportData.FIELDS.samples_read_counts) will help you detect sampling, and if required you will need to [handle pagination](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.page_token).

Answer (score 0):

While it is correct that you can request a quota increase. Which will increase the total number of requests that you can make this is still limited.

> In the API Console, there is a similar quota referred to as Requests per 100 seconds per user. By default, it is set to 100 requests per 100 seconds per user and can be adjusted to a maximum value of 1,000. But the number of requests to the API is restricted to a maximum of 10 requests per second per user.

[more info](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas)

## requests per user per 100 seconds

Is a user based quota it is linked to the maximum of 10 requests per second per user quota (10 queries per second (QPS) per IP address).  This is basically flood protection.  It prevents a single user from making to many requests against the api and there by making it hard for the rest of use to use the the api.

What you need to understand first is that 100 requests per user per second is very subjective.  When you run your request there is really no way for you to know what server your request will run on if your the only one running on that server then its possible you could kick off 100 request in 10 seconds and then be blocked for the next 90 seconds.

## quotaUser

The second thing you need to know is that user based normally means ip based so if these request may be going against different views but if its all running from the same Ip address this can cause some confusion and it assumes you are the same user.  To get around that you can use an alternate parameter called quota User which you can send a random string to this with every request and it can help it wont completely reduce it google tends to catch on to what you are doing eventually.

> quotaUser  An arbitrary string that uniquely identifies a user.
> Lets you enforce per-user quotas from a server-side application even in cases when the user's IP address is unknown. This can occur, for example, with applications that run cron jobs on App Engine on a user's behalf.
> You can choose any arbitrary string that uniquely identifies a user, but it is limited to 40 characters.
> Learn more about [Capping API usage.](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage)

## Implementing exponential backoff

Google normally recommends that you implement something called exponential backoff this basically means that you try a request if it fails then you wait a few seconds and try again if that fails then you wait twice as long as you waited before and then try again you do this about 10 times and normally you are able to get though.

If you are using one of the official google client libraries most of them have exponential backoff already implemented

## flood buster

I while ago i wrote an article about something i called flood buster its a way of keeping track of how fast i was going to try and prevent the user quota error the code is in C# you may find it useful [flood buster](https://www.daimto.com/google-apis-flood-buster/)

## not really an issue

while getting these errors may be ugly it doesn't really matter you should just make the request again.  Google does not count this error against you unless you do it constantly for hours at a time.

## 2000 requests per project 100 s

You need to remember that the number of requests your project can make In total per 100 seconds is 2000. This can not be increased.

So if you have two users each eating up 1000 requests per 100 seconds your going to hit the project based quota and there is nothing you can do about that.  Allowing a single user to eat all your quota is IMO not a very good idea unless this is a single user application.